# Updating HP bios (that comes packaged as rpm)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bios

So, I'm trying to update the bios of my HP Z230 workstation (don't ask why..).

It comes as a one-two punch: the 'xwbios' kernel module as a source rpm named hp-lxbios-mod..src.rpm and the 'lxbios' application rpm hp-lxbios..rpm that does the actual updating.

[Here's the link to downlad the rpm](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-z230-tower-workstation/5367825)  the file sp97093.tgz is under the BIOS tab on that page. After unpacking, under the lxbios folder you'll find the two rpms and the readme file describing rpm install procedure.

I am on Arch and I've given up trying to use some rpm tool and I am trying to install the software (or at least compile it) manually (and maybe build a PKGBUILD later).

**Kernel Module**

I have unpacked the hp-lxbios-mod..src.rpm which contains the rpm .spec file and another .tz with the actual stuff:

```
hp-lxbios-mod/mymod.c
hp-lxbios-mod/mymod.mod.c
hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.c
hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.mod.c
hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.h
hp-lxbios-mod/Makefile
hp-lxbios-mod/mkit
```

The Makefile looks (...) straightforward

```
#obj-m := mymod.o
obj-m := xwbios.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.ko

install:
    mkdir -p /opt/hp/hp-lxbios/xwkernel
    cp xwbios.ko /opt/hp/hp-lxbios/xwkernel/
```

the `mkit` is a bash script which finds where the kernel source is and launches make

```
 #!/bin/bash

if [ -d /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build ]; then
    ksrc=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
elif [ -d /lib/modules/`uname -r`/source ]; then
    ksrc=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/source
else
    echo "*** mkit: Error - unable to define kernel source location"
    exit -1
fi
echo "Kernel source dir is $ksrc"
# Setup kernel build of xwkernel module
rm -f $ksrc/xwkernel
ln -s /opt/hp/hp-lxbios/xwkernel $ksrc/xwkernel 
make -C $ksrc M=$PWD modules
```

make launches fine but I'm immediatly met with a compilation error

```
Kernel source dir is /lib/modules/5.3.6-arch1-1-ARCH/build
make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/5.3.6-arch1-1-ARCH/build'
  CC [M]  /home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.o
/home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.c:125:23: error: initialization of ‘long int (*)(struct file *, unsigned int,  long unsigned int ’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  125 |     .unlocked_ioctl = xwbios_ioctl,
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.c:125:23: note: (near initialization for ‘xwbios_fops.unlocked_ioctl’)
/home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.c: In function ‘xwbios_exit’:
/home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.c:666:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  666 |     if (pReqPwdBuffer)
      |     ^~
/home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.c:668:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  668 |  if (pRepsetGetInfo != NULL)
      |  ^~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod/xwbios.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1626: _module_/home/gls/Downloads/bios_iupdate/lxbios/hp-lxbios-mod] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/5.3.6-arch1-1-ARCH/build'
```

that I don't really know how to fix. I am thinking there is some compatibilty issue, maybe a missing flag I might put in there?

**Actual flashing of the bios**

Coming soon..

Comment: It may be easier to boot a live CD version of a supported version of RHEL if this is a one-time thing.  I  used to  keep an MSDOS floppy around just to do firmware updates

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw it required a custom kernel module and how old it was, I didn't bother trying to get it to compile with a modern kernel.

I decided to try installing it via a FreeDOS USB drive, which turned out to be a waste of time as well.

Instead, after unnecessarily putting together a boot disk, I ended up using the the option in the System Setup utility.

1. Extract the tarball: `tar xvf sp100126.tgz`
2. Place the flash image (eg `DOS Flash/J61_0396.bin`) at the root of a FAT formatted USB drive. (I actually copied the whole `DOS Flash/` directory to the root of the thumb drive, so I'm not sure whether other files like `flshuefi.cpu` might be necessary as well.)
3. Boot into the System Setup utility (`F10` at boot, or `ESC` to get the menu first).
4. Go to `File` -> `Flash System ROM`
5. Select USB drive. On a Z620 at least, the USB drive must be plugged into one of the black USB 2.0 ports. Presumably you could use a FAT formatted partition on an internal hard drive instead if that is more convenient.
6. Grab a cup of coffee, and come back to find
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Lol amazing =) I had actually given up as I managed to hackintosh my machine without the bios upgrade, but thanks for posting this!